# Cocoa Selector Question

Tags: cocoa, parameters, selector

I have a question on how to use a selector with multiple parameters. I need to toggle this:

> `-(void)openBackupNamed:(NSString *)name`

using this:

```
[backupList addItemWithTitle:file action:@selector(openBackupNamed:) keyEquivalent:@""];
```

I know that there is the `withObject:` parameter for these cases, but I can't do this in the `addItemWithTitle:action:keyEquivalent:` method or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you will have to create a new NSInvocation object and set it's index 2 parameter to your NSString (The 0- and 1-indexed parameters are reserved).

Example:

```
// Assuming:
NSString *myString = ...;

/* / */

NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(openBackupNamed:)]];
[invocation setSelector:@selector(openBackupNamed:)];
[invocation setTarget:self];
[invocation setArgument:&myString atIndex: 2];

[invocation invoke]; // or use invokeWithTarget: instead of the above setTarget method.
```

Read the ADC [NSInvocation Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Please mind the `setArgument` message. You have to pass it the **address** of your parameter (your string), not the actual object itself.

Comment: how can i get the address of the object?

Comment: use the & operator (read: address-of), it's in the example I posted. I suppose I should've made it more obvious.

Comment: oh right i see! I'd have gotten it using the %p descriptor, didnt know of the & operator - thanks!